# Lambda Expression Type Argument Cannot Be Inferred

Tags: c#, lambda

could someone help me to understand what is actually going on in the following example, so that i can *fish* for myself in the future.. as understand why the error is getting or how to resolve it without simply re-writing...

given this method method:

```
public static void DoNothing(string v)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Attempting to execute it like this, yields the error "*the type arguments for method .. cannot be inferred. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*" :

```
myList.Select(x => DoNothing(x)); // does not work
var r = myList.Select(x => DoNothing(x)); // just a ?
```

Howver, as soon as it returns something, i.e:

```
private static string ReturnString(string v)
{
    return v;
}
```

this works fine:

```
myList.Select(x => ReturnString(x)); // works
var r = myList.Select(x => ReturnString(x)); // IEnumerable<string>
```

so i guess it's something to do with a void return type?

can i never work due to the fact that nothing is returned, or is there some magic syntax that i'm missing / can't figure out(!)

only way i can seem to get this to function is as follows:

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    DoNothing(item);    // works fine.
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Select` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) expects the lambda expression in it to return value. Because `DoNothing(v)` is a `void` method, it doesn't return anything at all.

The error message is coming from generic inference where it would *try* to determine the type of variable produced by calling `Select` based on the result of the expression in it. But since there is no return type (`void` doesn't count), it complains.

Imagine if you chained another `Select` or `Where` call on it:

```
myList.Select(x => DoNothing(x)).Where(v => ????); //what is "v" here? void? That doesn't work

var value = myList.Select(x => DoNothing(x)).First(); //what is "value" here? void?
```

So you can see how it just doesn't work out.

Once you update it to call `ReturnString`, then the inference picks up on the `string` return type and everything is good to go.

```
myList.Select(x => ReturnString(x)).Where(v => v == "Hello World!"); // "v" is a string here, everything is fine.

string value = myList.Select(x => ReturnString(x)).First(); //what is "value" here? It's a "string" type as specified by "ReturnString"
```

Comment: ok, so that makes sense, essentially it will never work due to the void? is there anyway to inform the lamba that it is void, to 'understand' correctly... or is that besides the point?

Comment: If your intent is to "Select" meaning, "For each of the elements in `myList`, call this method -- I don't care about return values", then _typically_, that's what the `foreach` would be used for. LINQ is typically used for _querying_ data and ideally doesn't have side effects. That said, you can always roll your own extension method (like [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5,references)) method, although it's not done this way often, but if it works out for you, all the more power to you.

Comment: Although, if you _really, really, really_ want to do it, you can create a lambda statement with a throwaway value, and you also need to force it to iterate (and not be deferred): `myList.Select(x => { DoNothing(x); return 0; }).Count();` this is pretty nasty though. Either do your own extension method, or just use a standard `foreach` in a single line: `foreach(var x in myList) DoNothing(x);`

Comment: no, i don't want to do it that much... just looking to understand :D this quiestion came about as i was scooting through someone elses code in a solution i am working on, and they use it on a method that returns an awaitable task and then plops the resulting `List<Task>` into `task.WhenAll()`.. so i was just exploring the in's and out's as i had never seen it used like that..

Comment: @m1nkeh don't use `void` methods with `.Select(...)`, it makes absolutely no sense. `.Select(...)` is supposed to be used to "transform" the elements of the sequence into something else, for example convert a `List<string>` into `List<int>`

Comment: Yup, just to piggy back on Rui Jarimba's point, what you're trying to do with the void methods is make the equivalent of a `List<void>`. Can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer by Chris, you can maintain the current syntax using LINQ's `ForEach` method (assuming `myList` **is** actually a list).

```
myList.ForEach(x => DoNothing(x));
```